# How to estimate the N of a population in Rmark

Tags: r

I'm using Huggins for closed population model's in Rmark to analyze a population.
I did a model selection based on 5 candidates models and now I want to estimate the number of individual in that population (with aictabCustom).

I know that I need to use a model averaging method (like modavgCustom for example). But how can I estimate the N of that population?

Thank you!